# Why does Black Widow’s costume in Age of Ultron have glowing blue stripes?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron, costume

In *Age of Ultron*, Black Widow has glowing blue stripes across her costume. Bright blue stripes.

Why? Why would someone who's focused on stealth have glowing stripes on their uniform?  Is there a in-universe reason?

Comment: ...it looks cool?

Comment: I assumed it was related to her electrically-powered gizmos; an unobtrusive power source or something

Comment: @JasonBaker Yeah, I'm pretty sure http://marvel.wikia.com/Black_Widow%27s_Gauntlets is the short answer.

Comment: @JasonBaker [There may be precedence for that](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Self-Heating_Vest)

Comment: A self-heating vest? Hm. I don't remember now, but didn't the blue glow only happen during the mission inside the wrecked tanker? I thought about the electric gizmos as well, but she's used them in the past, without the glowing things.

Comment: @Petersaber I was thinking more generically a power source.  The vest generates its own power and is self-sustaining

Comment: the thing is that she didn't use the blueish costume throughout the entire movie, just some parts

Comment: "Why would someone focused on stealth have glowing stripes on their uniform?" Why would someone focused on stealth be on a team with a guy who wears a flag as a uniform, a flying red and gold metal man, a dude swinging a lightning hammer wearing a red cape, and a giant green monster?

Comment: They make for a good distraction? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An interview with [Yahoo News](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/avengers-age-of-ultron-new-costumes-suits-116571685312.html) suggests that the blue highlights are related to some new gadget of Widow's that fires electric blasts. From the article:

> Scarlett Johansson’s Black Widow suit got the most dramatic alteration. “I went electric,” said Johansson, who reprises the role of Black Widow (her fourth time as the Russian heroine) in reference to the Tron-esque new suit (courtesy of Robert Downey Jr.’s Tony Stark) that allows her to fire electrical blasts of energy at the bad guys.

And from the [interview itself](https://movies.yahoo.com/video/mark-ruffalo-feels-left-avengers-172240785.html):

> **Johansson:** I had a crazy...like electrical...blast sort of thing...ish. I went electric, I guess.

[Design & Trend got some on-set spoilers](http://www.designntrend.com/articles/15773/20140623/avengers-2-age-of-ultron-black-widow-first-electric-harley-film.htm), which also suggested an electrical theme:

> JoBlo has let loose another leak on a Marvel film, this time spilling details on Black Widow's costume for "Avengers: Age of Ultron."
>
> According to the report, the character will feature a "TRON-style" look that will feature electricity flowing through it, which will manifest as electroshock "widow sting" superpowers.

Comment: I don't remember that happening in the movie (BW shooting "blasts"). She used her electric batons, though

Comment: @Petersaber We may have to wait for the DVD (or for someone else to see it and confirm). I faintly remember something about it, but can't confirm 100%

Comment: This answer is correct, so no reason for me to add another one. The concept was called the "Widow's Sting" and was based on Chitauri blaster technology recovered from The Battle of New York (in the first movie). HYDRA's armored power-suit guys were based on the same technology - you can see them glowing blue during the battle at the beginning in the snowy woods. Apparently the scenes showing the sting in use were dropped in the final cut, however.

Comment: I would clarify that it's not *her* ability, but it's her suit/weapon's ability. She doesn't have and didn't gain super powers, but she does use new weapons.

Comment: @Omegacron Do you have a source saying that the Widow's Sting scenes were cut? What I can find on the Internet is mostly about the Black Widow toy thing.

Comment: @CreationEdge Edited, but it was in the quote...

Comment: Yeah, but isn't that quote based on pre-release info?

Comment: @JasonBaker not sure if the scenes were actually filmed & cut, or if the concept changed during filming. Original script and posters had her using her Widow's Bite attack - the prototype of it can be seen in Winter Soldier - but in the final film she uses the sticks instead.